# How to calculate past dates from the current date

Tags: ruby

1. Return dates as an array for "This week"

> ```
> def this_week   
>   if today == "wednesday"
>     return [date(sunday), ..., date(wednesday)]       
>   end 
> end
> ```

1. Return dates as an array for "Last week"

> ```
>  def last_week
>     return [date(last.sunday), ..., date(last.saturday)]
>   end
> ```

Comment: please don't, I have troubles implementing it

Comment: @Rpj what is your expected input and output? knowing that can give you better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `a_date.wday` give you [the day of the week](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-wday), you can find Sunday simply by removing it. From there, simply add Sunday and the next days in an array. For the last week, it's simply that each element of that array minus 7 days.

```
require 'date'
def this_week(today)
  sunday = today - today.wday
  week = [sunday]
  (1..6).each do |wday|
    week << sunday + wday
  end

  return week
end

def last_week(today)
  return this_week(today).map { |elem| elem - 7}
end
```

Comment: I ran this program, but it is returning the same dates for both methods. Did you cross verify this? http://pastie.org/7277026

Comment: it needs a Date object do `Date.today` not `Time.now`